# jQuery not reading the click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my jQuery looks alright but for some reason when I click the button the `console.log` doesn't fire. Anyone know why this might be?

This is the link to the jQuery that I have used. Sorry for the confusion. This one is up in the header. Although it still is not working.

```js
<head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Email Parser GUI</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles.css" />
        <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log("TEST ABOVE CLICKS");

                    $("#btnOn").click(function() {
                        console.log("TEST btnOn");
                        var value = 1;
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "URLphp",
                        data: {value : value},
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            console.log("check before send of ajax in btnOn");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                        }); 
                     });

                    $("#btnOff").click(function() {
                        console.log("TEST btnOff");
                            var value = 0;
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "URL.php",
                            data: {value : value},
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: true,
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                console.log("check before send of ajax in btnOff");
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                            }); 
                    });
                });
                </script>
    </head>
```

Then in the body tags

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btnOn">On/Off</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button id="btnOn" name="btnOn" value="1" class="btn btn-success">On</button>
                    <button id="btnOff" name="btnOff" value="0" class="btn btn-danger">Off</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you included jquery library file?

Comment: Which console.log doesn't fire?

Comment: @MrGeek I think the second one ("TEST btnOn")

Comment: But it does work?

Comment: The code snippet works!!!! So, as brk suggested, I think you missed something

Comment: I'd imagine you've not added the jquery library, as suggested above

Comment: Does it work, if you remove the call to $.ajax()?

Comment: the query library file is there...so its really odd that on the page it doesnt work but the snippet here does.

Comment: J.Brown even with the ajax call commented out it still doesnt fire off the console.log(TEST btnOn)

Comment: As I see in your code snippet, you have added a link to jQuery on both your html and external javascript file. just why in javascript? Remove the link in your external javascript file and it will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery `on`,

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnOn", function() {
    console.log("TEST btnOn");
 });
```

Comment: This is best for dynamically created elements. OP's code doesn't seem to be like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Check that you actually have jQuery enabled

2) Try Dan Philip's answer, using .on instead of .click :

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnOn", function() {
    console.log("TEST btnOn");
 });
```

3) Compare your code and the code in the snippet, silly mistakes always happen and perhaps you missed a letter in some selector. An easy way to check is to create a brand new button.

Answer (score 0):

Both in the code snippet and in the code posted in the question you missed to enclose the javascript code between `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("TEST!!!!!!");
        $("#btnOn").click(function() {

            // ...

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button id="btnOn" name="btnOn" value="1" class="btn btn-
 success">On</button>
 </body>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("TEST!!!!!!");
    $("#btnOn").click(function () {
        console.log("TEST btnOn");
        var value = 1; $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "URL.php",
            data: { value: value },
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log("check before send of ajax in btnOn");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
  });
</script>


 ----------

 <b>Do it like this It Will work !!!</b>
```